# Highcharts/Highstocks: Chart disappears when value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart made from highstock, and the chart seems to disappear when the last value is all 0. The chart will start to show up when I move the navigation/scroll bar to move away from the last value.

Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/P7kZR/

And since stackoverflow has a rule where you have to post code. Here is some of it

function fill_series() {

```
//CHART 2
payrate_series = {
    type: 'line',
    name: "Pay Rate",
    data: payrate_data
}
chart2_series[0] = payrate_series;
arpu_series = {
    name: "ARPU",
    data: arpu_data,
    yAxis: 1
}
chart2_series[1] = arpu_series;
arppu_series = {
    name: "ARPPU",
    data: arppu_data,
    yAxis: 1
}
chart2_series[2] = arppu_series;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are having division by zero errors. You should make sure that the denominator is not zero. For example:

```
var arpu = parseFloat(record['sales'])/parseFloat(record['dau']);
```

Comment: I have no divisions, but my graph plotted a non-digit value which forced the line to disappear as well. Thanks Dr.Flink your solution led in the right direction for my fix.